# Dropping a ball with increasing masses and measuring the time until it no longer bounces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, gravity, energy-conservation

How could one theoretically explain that when one drops several balls with different masses from the hand, the bounces are less if the ball has larger mass and comes to rest after a shorter period of time?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/663675/whats-the-best-answer-to-how-many-bounces-until-the-ball-stops

Comment: It's not just the mass. You effectively are asking why the collisions of different balls with the same floor have different [_elasticity_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision). The answer is more complicated than I can explain, but it has more to do with the material properties of the stuff that the balls are made of than it has to do with their mass.

Answer (score 0):

if they are made of the same material then a ball with large mass will bounce to large height due to high force it landed with

Comment: Maybe you could expand to include why would this be?