# Looking for a physics model of a ball's bounce

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, collision

For a physics project , I will try to study the deviation of a sliced tennis ball after its bounce. So I'm looking at the influence of the linear speed and the speed of rotation of a ball on its deviation angle after the bounce. I need to do some experiments to verify a physics model (can be a theory or an equation). Unfortunately, I didn't find out this model and I'm a bit blocked now.

Can somebody help me by providing me a physics model of the relationship between the linear speed and the rotational during the bounce and the angle of deviation after the bounce? Or a link to somewhere I could find what I need?

Comment: Look here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/663675/whats-the-best-answer-to-how-many-bounces-until-the-ball-stops

Answer (score 0):

During the impact a frictional force is applied by the horizontal ground to the ball surface, altering the rotational momentum and (neglecting heat or other losses) transfering it to/from the horizontal momentum.

rotational momentum = mVr

- for a solid unifrom sphere r is thye distance from the ball center to the center of rotational mass, the radius R/sqrt(2) (because half the ball's mass is further out than this).

horizontal momentum = mv

- v is the horizontal component of veloicity.

If we assume, for simplicity, that the impact stops the rotation, then

d(mv)=mVR/sqrt(2)

It's fine for starters, however, in reality a ball will slip or slide depending on the friction coefficients and the force of impact, which is somewhat more involved. For a game like tennis I would model it simply for impacts with the court by removing a fixed proportion of the rotational momentum, say 60%. It's a guess.
Impacts with the rackets are more tricky as the surface is no longer horizontal and it is moving too, but assuming 100% momentum transfer here is probably a good start.

I hope that helps.